# 'odoo-bin' command not working in my Odoo 13.0 (Windows installation)

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

I'm following this tutorial "Building a Module" from the Odoo Developer Documentation:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/howtos/backend.html

I'm able to set-up a module through:
`python odoo-bin scaffold openacademy addons`.  And it successfully creates a subdirectory containing a bunch of standard files for a module in my addons directory.

Then going thru the tutorial, codes have been added/edited in some of the files; hence, a certain command to save these changes must be invoked:
`python odoo-bin -u openacademy`.  However, it seems to be not working as my terminal simply freezes.  The terminal doesn't start a new line, so I have to 'Ctrl+C'.

I also noticed that 'odoo-bin' also have the same response(freezing terminal) upon invoking other commands such as:
`python odoo-bin -c odoo.conf`
`python odoo-bin -r dbuser -w dbpassword --addons-path=addons -d mydb`

I also suspect that it would be the same case with other more commands

To wrap it up, the **'odoo-bin' command only works with the 'scaffold' sub-command.  But with other commands, it causes the terminal to freeze eternally, unless you 'Ctrl+C'**

I'm confused.  Can somebody help me?

Comment: When you update module from command line, you need to pass database name. So for `-u`, you need `-d`. 
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/reference/cmdline.html

Comment: I tried this ```python odoo-bin -u openacademy -d test```, where 'test' is the name of my PostgresSQL database.  The result is still the same, the terminal freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows Odoo behaves a bit differently than in Linux. The easiest way is to download Odoo Windows installer from https://www.odoo.com/download and then run it with defaults. That generates an Odoo server for you in http://localhost:8069/.

Then just copy-paste your custom add-on folder to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons` and restart the Odoo service from Windows' Control Panel.

Note that to test new version of your add-on it may also be necessary to first enable developer mode, then go to Apps, select Update Apps List, select your app and upgrade it. To make sure your changes are applied be liberal with the version number increases in manifest.py.

Note that as `C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 13.0\server\odoo\addons` is a protected directory, edit the documents first in your version controlled git clone directory and copy only ready-to-be-executed code to Odoo's directory.